# Calculation keeps giving a NaN result

Tags: javascript, html, math

I was given a formula where below:

```
weightdifference = (|crushedWeight - weightBA| / weightBA )* 100%
```

where *weightBA* and *crushedWeight* are values of input texts. I did make a function which stated below:

```
function calDiffWeight() {
    var weightDS = document.getElementById("weightDS");
    var crushedWeight = document.getElementById("crushedWeight");
    var abs = -1;
    var diffWeight = ((crushedWeight - weightDS) * abs) / weightDS * 100;
    document.getElementById("diffWeight").value = diffWeight;
}
```

and for the absolute calculation in `|crushedWeight - weightBA|` how should i do it?

Comment: Use parseFloat() on values

Comment: Start with sending the output to the console, especially `weightDS` and `crushedWeight`. Chance is pretty big these values aren't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I made the following changes:

- You get the elements for weightDS and crushedWeight but you never got the values from those inputs;
- Converted the values to floating number before using them for the calculation
- Use `Math.abs()` to make the number absolute.

```js
const
  form = document.getElementById('form');
  
form.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmit);

function onFormSubmit() {
  event.preventDefault();
  calDiffWeight();
}
function calDiffWeight() {
    var weightDS = parseFloat(document.getElementById("weightDS").value);
    var crushedWeight = parseFloat(document.getElementById("crushedWeight").value);
    var diffWeight = (Math.abs(crushedWeight - weightDS)) / weightDS * 100;
    document.getElementById("diffWeight").value = diffWeight;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>
    WeightDS:
    <input type="number" id="weightDS"/>
  </label>
  <label>
    Crushed Weight:
    <input type="number" id="crushedWeight"/>
  </label>
  
  <button>Calculate</button>
</form>

<p>Result</p>
<input type="number" id="diffWeight"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `weightDS` is an input box I would recommend `document.getElementById("weightDS").value;`, because with just `getElementById` you simply get the dom node. not the value of whatever it may contain.

a bigger and nicer answer is here [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The method `document.getElementById();` returns a HTML element. Obviously you can't do maths with a HTML element. So you're propably looking for the `value` attribute of that HTML element. Since it is a string, parse it to an integer (or float depending on your situation).

```
var weightDS = parseInt(document.getElementById("weightDS").value);
var crushedWeight = parseInt(document.getElementById(document.getElementById("crushedWeight").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .value after document.getElementById("weightDS")

```
function calDiffWeight() {
var weightDS = document.getElementById("weightDS").value;
var crushedWeight = document.getElementById("crushedWeight").value;
var abs = -1;
var diffWeight = ((crushedWeight - weightDS) * abs) / weightDS * 100;
document.getElementById("diffWeight").value = diffWeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('elementId');` returns a DOM element. In order to get the value you have to call the `value` property.

Here is a solution for your example:

```
var weightDS = parseInt(document.getElementById("weightDS").value);
var crushedWeight = parseInt(document.getElementById(document.getElementById("crushedWeight").value);
```